# using converting string to tinyint (bool) with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way, using a `TRIGGER` or preferably some MySql function I'm not aware of, to automatically assign the value of a `TINYINT` column to '1' if ANY value is passed into it?

For example if I have columnA (`TINYINT`) and I `INSERT` "doggybones" into that column:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (columnA) VALUES ("doggybones")
```

... then mysql would automatically assign a value of "1" to `columnA` instead of kicking up an error about trying to stick a `string` into a `TINYINT` column?

It should also work so that if I insert "" - a blank value but the `INSERT` statement will still list it, like so:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (columnA) VALUES ("")
```

... then the column will receive a value of 0.

Note: I know I could filter my values to just INSERT 0's and 1's but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this on the mysql side.

Comment: the idea is to be able to quickly poll the table to see if certain columns are true or false

Comment: Add an extra column that is set by the trigger then. You can keep, empty or NULL the original value in columnA as you need

Comment: there are lot of columns that need this BOOL value and it seems a waste to multiply the number of columns needed by 2. Are you saying that my above question is not possible?

Comment: Correct. datatypes are strictly enforced. Is the flag set per column or per row? If per row, it is just one extra column. Or why not test for "" (empty string)?

Comment: per column, and as I mentioned in the "Note:" I know I could test for "" but wanted to see what was available to do this in sql. If you thrown your last comment into an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL (all flavours) enforce data types strictly.
This happens before any trigger code runs.

You'll have to test for "" (empty string)